# How do I modify a frame once it's created?

Tags: frames

I want to manipulate a frame after it's created. I thought that I could do this with an 'after-make-frame-functions hook as a callback but it seems to return too early.

This is the sample code that demonstrates the issue:

```
(defvar test-frame nil)

(defun finish-frame-setup( frame )
  (message "test frame is %s" (frame-live-p test-frame)))

(defun test-frame-callback()
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'finish-frame-setup t nil)
  (setq test-frame (make-frame)))
```

and

```
M-x eval-buffer
M-x test-frame-callback
```

results in

```
test frame is nil
```

I'd appreciate any assistance.
Emacs 24.4 on win32

Comment: You're checking `test-frame` instead of `frame` ?

Comment: I want to act only on test-frame. frame is valid but (eq test-frame frame) is still nil.

Comment: Ohhh. the setq only happens after the frame is made and the hook is called before test-frame is assigned to the resulting frame. How would I act on this specific frame?

Comment: Well... act on `frame`? That's the very reason why this argument is passed to the hook functions iiuc.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `after-make-frame-functions` is called before the frame is assigned to `test-frame`.

The solution is to simplify and avoid the callback

```
(defun test-frame-callback()
  (interactive)
  (setq test-frame (make-frame))
  (message "test frame is %s" (frame-live-p test-frame))))
```